# Selenium select option

Tags: python, select, selenium

I have multiple select option as:

```
<select id="auto_year" class="element" onchange="loadMakes(this.value);" name="auto_year">
 <option value="0000">- Year -</option>
 <option value="2014">2014</option>
 <option value="2013">2013</option>
 <option value="2012">2012</option>
 <option value="2011">2011</option>
</select>

<select id="auto_make" class="element" onchange="loadModels(document.getElementById('auto_year').value, this.value);;" name="auto_year">
 <option value="0000">- Make-</option>
</select>
```

Initially, the option inside the **select id = "auto_make"** is empty. But as i select one of the option from the **select id ="auto_year"**, the option appears. I'm facing problem in selecting values. My code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get(certain_url)  
html_source = browser.page_source  

yearoption_val = browser.find_element_by_id('auto_year')
for yearoption in yearoption_val.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
 if yearoption.text == '- Year -':
  continue
 else:
  yearoption.click()
  itemmake_val = browser.find_element_by_id('auto_make')
  for itemmake in itemmake_val.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
   if (itemmake.text == r'\- Make \(\d+ items\) \-' or '- Model -'):
    continue
  else:
   itemmake.click()
```

The problem with the code is it selects 2014 and moves into 2013 without looking for option in **id = auto_make** for 2014. Any help or suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a small sleep after the `yearoption.click()` code? This will make sure that the onclick method can execute.

Comment: Sleeps are never wise in an automation script and should be avoided

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried instantiating a Select object? Here is an example from the Selenium site in Python;

```
# available since 2.12
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("select"))
select.deselect_all()
select.select_by_visible_text("Edam")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem 2 weeks ago. I tried a number of different options and ended up with the method below. The issue was `click()` or `Select()` did make the selection but failed to set the value. The only thing you might be missing is sending a  key to the select object.

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

```
def select_option_from_a_dropdown(self, select_object, option_value):
    """
     To select options in "<select>" in selenium we need to select the option first and then need
    to send ENTER key on the select.
    """
    options = select_object.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    for option in options:
        self.log.info(option.text)
        if option.text.upper() == option_value.upper():
            option.click()
    select_object.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

If you are facing the same problem as I did, you just need to perform `yearoption_val.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` after `yearoption.click()`.

**English is not my first language. Please edit the answer as appropriate